# Estimating the modulus of continuity of translation in $L^2$ by a Sobolev norm of the function

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

For any $s\in \mathbb{R}$ define the Hilbert space $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ by means of norm $$\|f\|^2_{H^s}=|\widehat{f}(0)|^2+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n|^{2s}|\widehat{f}(n)|^2.$$

Show that for any $0\leq s\leq 1$ one has $\|f(\cdot +\theta)-f\|_2\leq 2\pi \|f\|_{H^s}|\theta|^s$.
How would you prove this estiamte, I tried Prseval formula but it is not working. How can I form the constant $2\pi$ frpom my original equation.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{T}$ the torus? If so, why do all your functions have a single number as argument?

Comment: yes I forget to mention, $\mathbb{T}=[0,1)$, sorry for the confusion. That is the way the problem is formatted

Comment: You can reduce the left hand side of the inequality to $$||e^{-2\pi i \theta}-1)\widehat{f}(n)||^2_{l^2}$$

Comment: I edited the title because $H^s$ is usually called a Sobolev space (e.g., [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/396281/) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889447/)). It's true these are also Hilbert spaces, but the name *Hilbert space* is used for any complete inner product space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third comment is on the right track, but you miss $n$ in the exponent: *you can reduce the left hand side of the inequality to* $$\|(e^{-2\pi i n\theta }-1)\widehat{f}(n)\|^2_{l^2}$$ 
To be more explicit, the desired inequality can be stated as 
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} |e^{-2\pi i n\theta }-1|^2 |\hat f(n)|^2 \le (2\pi)^2 |\theta|^{2s} \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \max(|n|^{2s},1) |\hat f(n)|^2
\tag{1}$$

After looking at (1) for a while, one realizes that it either holds elementwise, or fails. Namely, if 
$$|e^{-2\pi i n\theta }-1|^2  \le (2\pi)^2 |\theta|^{2s}  \max(|n|^{2s},1),\quad \forall  n\in\mathbb Z \tag{2}$$
then (1) is true. And if (2) fails for some $n$, then (1) fails, because   the function $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i nt}$ is a counterexample.

So... is (2) true? For $n=0$ it is, so we can assume $n\ne 0$ and simplify (2) to 
$$|e^{-2\pi i n\theta }-1|   \le  2\pi  |n\theta|^{ s}    \quad \forall  n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\} \tag{3}$$

The function $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is $1$-Lipschitz, since its derivative has unit modulus. Hence, $|e^{-2\pi i n\theta}-1|\le 2\pi |n \theta|$. This implies (3) in the case $|n\theta|\le 1$. And if $|n\theta|>1$, then the right hand side of (3) is greater than $2\pi$, while the left hand side is at most $2$.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. This makes it clear to others that the question has been answered.

Comment: For $||f||_{H^s}\leq 1$ you can also find a rate of convergence of $||S_Nf-f||_2$ in $N$ right?

Comment: This is a different question. You can ask it as a new question. But the answer is yes: the tail is $O(N^{-s})$.